# QUERY ACROSS TABS USING DROP DOWN

Tags: google-sheets

I have a workbook that is made of several sheets.  Each sheet is named individually i.e. 23-002234-0001.   I have created a sheet that we will use to print certain pieces of data in a report-style format. Is it possible to use a query function to query different sheets based on cell with a drop-down that will list each tab name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can follow the sample below, where `A1` is where I have the drop-down with the sheet names and whenever you change the value in the drop-down then it will query the data from that specific sheet:

`=QUERY(INDIRECT(A1 & "!A1:A"), "Select A")`

`!A1:A` in the formula is the range that I want from the sheet, you can change it to what you need, in my case I just wanted column `A1:A` and `"Select A"` in case you're querying more than one column then you specify which one you want.

[image: Sample of how the formula works]

**Reference:**

[INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)